# How to add text when onmouseover is activated

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

```
<div id="first_caption">
<p style="float: left; clear: left">
<img 
    src="http://www.ottawaskeptics.org/images/stories/lightbulb.jpg" 
    onmouseover="this.src='http://pngimg.com/upload/small/bulb_PNG1251.png'" 
    onmouseout="this.src='http://www.ottawaskeptics.org/images/stories/lightbulb.jpg'"  
    height="50" width="50"
>
<p>How can you save money to do the things you love, and live a healthier life? rollover on the light bulb to see how!</p>
</div>
```

This is the code. what i am trying to do is make a text appear below the first paragraph when i hover over the image.

Comment: what text are you trying to make appear? You need to supply more information.

Answer (score 0):

Add div or span, assign an ID and then on event add values to the ID.

```
var div = document.getElementById('divID');

div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'Extra stuff';
```

here is the complete example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myClick()">click here</a>
<div id="heading1">
This is existing text. 
</div>

<script>
function myClick(){
text = "This text is added.";
document.getElementById('heading1').innerHTML  = document.getElementById('heading1').innerHTML + text;
}
</script>
```

Comment: im not very strong in javaScript, but if you have anything in PHP or html ill take it.

Comment: well, learn then. get javascript essentials from Lynda.com for example.
I added complete html page example.

Comment: @user3612995 You can't do anything with mouseover from php.